# How can I make my display: table; DIV fill the horizontal width of the DIV containing it?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="rep_tb0" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="rep_tr0" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="rep_td0" style="width: 100%" id="ActivityLog">Activity Log</div>
    </div>
</div>

.rep_tb0 {display: table; }
.rep_tb0 {padding: 5px;}
.rep_tb0 {border-collapse:collapse; }
.rep_tr0 {display: table-row;}
.rep_td0 {display: table-cell; padding: 5px; vertical-align:top; }
.rep_td0 {border: 1px solid #666; }
```

What I would like is for the table that has the word Activity Log to extend horizontally to fill the DIV that contains it. Note that DIV has a width set but it may easily change. As you can see I tried setting the width in three places but none worked.

How can I make it fill the area horizontally without setting the width in pixels.

Please don't forget I'm using display: table; These are not normal DIVs :-)

Comment: Why do you need those table-related `display` values?

Comment: When I test this code "rep_td0" takes the entire width, as it should do. Which browser are you using? Are you sure you doesn't need a table after all? All is ok if it's for displaying some data..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make a container of the size that I want and relative position; and an inner div with absolute values, like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Then the css would look something like this:

```
#container{
    width:70%;
    min-width:600px;
    height: 600px;
    background:#000;
    border:medium;
    border-color:#CCC;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:block;
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try two things. Get rid of the hardcoded `width:100%` in the `rep_td0` div and then do `margin:0px auto` in the css without any width. If that does not work, trying giving the `reptb0` div a width with pixels instead of percents and do the same for the `reptd0` div.